# response from post request is empty

Tags: spring-boot, java-7, rest

I have the following WS i request from post man with the following parameters:
[image]

and i have the following from the postman console

[image]
I am trying to request the WS with the following piece of code :

```
logger.info("generating new token from "+URL);
expritation = new Date();
        
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
MultiValueMap<String, String> map= new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
map.add("userUid", userUid);
map.add("appUid", appUid);
map.add("ttl", ttl);
restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor(WsLogin, WsPassword));
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(URL, map , String.class);
return response.getBody();
```

I am able to see the response body in postman but the response.getBody() is emty in the java code.

Can someone explain to me why it is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean you are seeing the response body in the Postman but not in your prog? Did you try to debug of print the response value before returning from the method?

Comment: Yes, i did. it's empty

Comment: Pretty interesting. Can you please post the screenshot of response from the postman console? I would like to see what do you see in the RequestHeader and RequestBody section of it.

Comment: No your screenshot is from the Postman UI it seems, console looks like following :-
Request Body
Response Headers
Date: Mon, 15 Feb 2021 17:24:05 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
CP-TRACE-ID: a6a126253730a353

There is a dedicated UI with the name of console in Postman.

Comment: Oh, you are totaly right. i edited my question again

Comment: Just for the sake of troubleshooting, Can you please add the dependency of Gson to your boot app and try to pint the map

gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
system.out.println(gson.toJson(map));

Comment: i have the followin { "userUid": [ "userUid" ], "appUid": [ "appUid" ], "ttl": [ "3600" ] } .
it's not te same so, i edited my map to the following :
Map<String,String> map= new HashMap<>();
map.put("userUid", userUid);
map.put("appUid", appUid);
map.put("ttl", ttl);